# C++ forward iterator arithmetic

Tags: c++

Below is a simple program to print the position within a vector of a small range of ints.

```
int mynumbers [] = { 3, 9, 0, 2, 1, 4, 5 };
vector<int> v (mynumbers, mynumbers + 7);
int m1[] = {9, 0, 2 };
vector<int>::iterator it = find_end (v.begin(), v.end(), m1, m1+3);
if (it != v.end())
    cout << "Found at position: " << it-v.begin() << endl;//LINE I
```

The program as expected prints

> Found at position: 1

the find_end function returns a forward iterator. 
Logically it makes no sense for me to do so but when I change 'LINE I' to

```
    cout << "Found at position: " << it+v.begin() << endl;//LINE I
```

I get a compile error.
I know I should be using 'distance' however I am just trying to familiarise myself with the limitations of the various iterator types

Thanks

Comment: What would such an operation do?

Comment: It doesn't make sense and it doesn't compile. I'd call that a win. What's the problem? It seems similar to asking why `dos#&*$#%ifosidfjsdo;` doesn't compile.

Comment: Why are you using both an array and an std::vector?

Comment: what would it mean to add 2 pointers? Like `int* p; p - p; /* ok */ p + p; /* error */`

Comment: @ThomasMatthews, Probably a lack of C++11's ability to initialize a vector like that.

Comment: *"the `find_end` function returns a forward iterator"* The function **template** `find_end` returns *at least* a forward iterator. In fact, it return type is the same type as the type of its first parameter. Since `vector<int>::iterator` is a Random Access Iterator, this `find_end` function template specialization also returns a Random Access Iterator.

Comment: C++11 can initialize a vector like that, but previous compilers can't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that there is an operation defined for `b - a`, where `b` and `a` are of the same iterator types, but there is no operation defined for `b + a`.

Sources:

Non-normative: cppreference, [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator)

Normative: N4140, [random.access.iterators] Table 111

Answer (score 3):

`it` is an iterator, it represents a *location* where an object is.

You say "logically it makes no sense for me to do so..." about `it+v.begin()`, which is right, because you're adding two locations.  What do you get when you add the location of Californa to the location of New York? The question literally makes no sense.

However, you can take the distance between two locations: `it-v.begin()`.  Not sure exactly what you're asking, but I hopefully covered it.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track.

But I think the `distance` that you mention in your question is your actual solution: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/distance/

This is your situation:

```
begin() --> 3
it -->      9
            0
            2
            1
            4
            5
```

`distance(v.begin(), it)` will tell you how far those two pointers are apart. (In this case 1).

Now keep in mind under the hood `distance` will just do the same subtraction that you do in this case.

How you should think about it is like this, `v.begin()` is an address and so is `it`.

> `v.begin()` is 0x0100
>   `it` is 0x0104

when you subtract them you're going to get `(0x0104 - 0x0100) / sizeof(int)` so you'll get 1.